# Tab length in Sublime Text on Mac not correct

Tags: macos, fonts, tabs, sublimetext3, retina-display

I bought a new iMac 27 inch and one of the first things I did was installing my text editor of choice, Sublime Text. After a bit of writing code I noticed that the indentation with tabs is to wide. In the bottom left corner it says `Tab Size: 4` but in fact one tab is as wide as 12 spaces. When changing the setting to `Tab Size: 2` one tab is as wide as 6 spaces.

Could it be that Sublime multiplies the length of one tab with 3 because of the large resolution (2560 x 1440)? Does anybody know how to fix this issue?

**EDIT:**

I use the `Ubuntu Mono` font with 16px font size. When setting the option `Indent Using Spaces` everything works as expected. Here an image of the current situation with `Tab Size: 4`.

[image]

Comment: Can you attach an image showing the issue? Are you using a proportional or fixed-width font? What happens when you set the Indent Using Spaces setting?

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I edited the question. Ubuntu Mono should be a fixed-with font though.

Comment: Ok, this would be a workaround. But why does Sublime behave in such a way? This problem could occur in another application without this option

Comment: you don't appear to have Ubuntu Mono installed on your system, and it's substituting in a proportional font. Try setting your font to Menlo (included on all OS X systems) and see if the tab sizes match up.

Comment: Thank you, changing the font to `Menlo` solved the problem. Sorry for that, I transferred my Sublime configuration from my laptop running Ubuntu. If you add your solution as answer I can mark it as solution and therefore the question as solved.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sublime works fine on my iMac, so the screen resolution isn't the issue. Instead, I would suspect that you are using a proportional font instead of a fixed-width one. A likely cause of this is lacking the specified font on your new system - I use a [non-system font](http://www.fontsquirrel.com/fonts/Liberation-Mono) with Sublime, and so need to install it on new computers before everything looks right to me.

With a proportional font, spaces tend to be rather small, especially when compared to "large" characters like D, W, e, s, etc., that take up a proportionally larger amount of horizontal space (hence the name proportional font). Additionally, a tab character may be calculated by Sublime to be a certain size as a function of the pixel size of the font, and so may bear no relation to the actual number of space characters it takes to equal the size of the tabstop. I know that in programs such as MS Word, tabstops are set in fractions of an inch (or cm, or pica, or whatever), and have no relation to the type or size of font being used.

All this is simplified with fixed-width fonts. All characters (even Unicode ones) take up the same horizontal width. Sublime calculates the width of tabs using the standard character width, so everything is consistent.

All that being said, how to fix your problem? The easiest way to determine if this actually *is* the problem is to set your `"font_face"` setting to Menlo, an Apple-designed fixed-width font that's been on all their systems since the early days of the Macintosh. If your code goes back to looking like normal, that was the issue. You can then search for whichever font you were using before, if you like, or take a look at my favorite font, linked above, or just keep using Menlo if you're not too picky.

Good luck!